How do I refresh android studio file directory?
I'm currently using android studio and I added in a README.md file to my project. But the issue here is that it's not showing the file on android studio's file directory. However, if I were to check the project folder locally, I can see the README.md file on there. In addition to that, it won't allow me to add a README.md file because I already have a file with that name which exists. So, the README.md file clearly exists and I did add it to my android studio project. But the underlying issue here is that it's not displaying this file on the file directory inside of android studio. I'm not sure what is causing the problem as this is my first time using android studio. What would be a solution that resolves this problem?
I have tried right clicking the root directory and clicked on reload on disk. I have also tried clicking synchronize with gradle. But neither of these buttons did anything to display this newly added file on my project file directory for android studio.

Select "Project Files" in your project view

